# vim or word to display color coded output with color I am using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, vim, cpu-word

I am using  code to display color output on terminal and output file.

when i open output with vim or any windows word document  i am seeing along with code values

code:

```
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

Output file when open word and vim:

```
 [92mProfile Name xyz      ok [0m                                                           |
```

Is there way i can remove coded values when i open with vim or word  for this purpose or  i need to use some other tools to achieve this.

Even it will be great if it shows in colors.

Note: I am using python script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your taking the raw output (as evidenced by the terminal code strings: HEADER, OKGREEN, ...) and reading that into a text editor, aka Vim.

While Vim can edit this, it is typically not meant to be used that way.  A more proper way is to NOT output those terminal codes and just edit the resulting text.

However, there does exist a plugin (AnsiEsc - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) that seems to be able to do what you want: NOT show those pesky escape codes and instead hide them and show the text in the editor as it probably should on the terminal.

Try that.